# Where can I find the element's property code in WAF BookLibrary Sample

Tags: wpf, waf-framework-c#

I am studying WAF and WPF (I am quite newbie).

I have analyzed heaps of time to figure out how the elements property are set in BookLibrary sample but I can't figure out. 
[image]

When I look at the Remove button code at ToobarTray in BookListView.xaml

```
<Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}">
    <AccessText Text="{x:Static p:Resources.RemoveMenu}"/>
</Button>
```

There is no property to disable this button.
Where is the disabled property code?
Also I cannot find the code to enable this button when user select a row in datagrid.
How this enable/disable works?

Same as Toolbar tray buttons in ShellWindow.

```
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" Content="{StaticResource UndoImage}" ToolTip="{x:Static p:Resources.Undo}"/>
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Redo" Content="{StaticResource RedoImage}" ToolTip="{x:Static p:Resources.Redo}"/>
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" Content="{StaticResource CutImage}" ToolTip="{x:Static p:Resources.Cut}"/>
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" Content="{StaticResource CopyImage}" ToolTip="{x:Static p:Resources.Copy}"/>
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" Content="{StaticResource PasteImage}" ToolTip="{x:Static p:Resources.Paste}"/>
```

Above buttons definitely has opacity property,
however there is no opacity in code level.
Also when a user change the data in the datagrid, those button's opacity change to 100%.
but I cannot find the code about this.
How this things works?

Could you explain how those things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"` binds to a `DelegateCommand` member in the ViewModel (`DelegateCommand` is an implementation of `ICommand` provided by WAF). `DelegateCommand` has a constructor that can take two parameters. The first parameter specifies what to do when you click the button. The second specifies when the button is enabled. For example, it may look something like this:

```
...
RemoveCommand= new DelegateCommand(Remove, CanRemove);
...

private void Remove()
{
    //Remove logic
}

private bool CanRemove()
{
    //When you are able to remove. For example, return SelectedItem != null;
}
```

If you browse through the viewmodel code, you should find something similar to above. When `CanRemove` returns false, the button/Menu item will be disabled. To propagate changes of this state, `DelegateCommand` implements `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`. This is how the button becomes disabled even though it is not explicitly present in XAML.

Comment: The remove command is defined at the Waf.BookLibrary.Library.Applications.BookController constructor: removeCommand = new DelegateCommand(RemoveBook, CanRemoveBook);